# how to set nutch to extract content of only urls present on seed file

Tags: apache, web-crawler, hbase, nutch

I am using nutch 2.3 and I am trying to get the html content of some urls present on seed.txt file which I pass to nutch into HBase.

So the problem is as below---

First crawl:
Everything runs fine and I get the data into HBase with url as the row key.

Second Run:
when i run the crawl for second time with different urls I see there are so many urls for the fetching job is running while I have only one url in my seed file.

So my question is how can make sure that nutch **only** crawls and get the html contents of the urls present in seed.txt and not the out links present in urls html content of seed.txt

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to fetch only domains that are given in seed file. For that update nutch-site.xml as following

```
  <property>
   <name>db.ignore.external.links</name>
   <value>true</value>
  </property>
```

Comment: This only ignores links to external hosts. It does not prevent fetching of pages that are within the same domain.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have to customize nutch to implement above functionality

Answer (score 0):

You might keep the iteration of the crawl command as "1" and then nutch will crawl only the urls present in seed.txt file.

e.g.

```
bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=<solrUrl> <seed-dir> <crawl-dir> 1
```

Also, you can restrict the outer links by configuring your **regex-urlfilter.txt** present in conf directory.

```
#accept anything else
+http://doamin.com
```

Comment: thanks for replying rocksta first I would like to ask you can you please tell me what is the meaning of the text which you want me to insert in regex-urlfilter.txt and can you please elaborate what is the meaning of the crawl command because I dont think so my crawl command handles any -i switches